# PHP duplicate staffID

Tags: php

- staff table
  [image]
- code

  ```
  <?php
   //db configuration
   $q = "select * from staff";
   $r = mysqli_query($dbc, $q);
   $num_rows = mysqli_num_rows($r);

   $staffID = array();
   while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($r, MYSQLI_ASSOC))
   {
       $staffID[] = $row['staffID'];
   }

   for($i = 0; $i < $num_rows; $i++)
   {
       if($staffID[$i] == $staffID[$i+1])
       {
           $remark = "Not OK. Multiple staff ID selected.";
           $i++;
       }
       else
       {  
           $remark = "OK.";
       }
       $data[$i] = $staffID[$i].','.$remark.'<br />';
  }

  $list = array($data);
  print_r($list);
  ?>
  ```
- From above code, I want to check whether the staffID got duplicate.
- Expected output
  0001, OK. 
  0002, Not OK. Multiple staffID.
   
  0003, OK. 
  0004, OK.
- However, I get another error as below:
  **Undefined offset: 5 in play.php on line X.**
  How do I solve it?

Comment: first of all, staffID must be unique (make it from DB setting) and you must not test this
 - second: you should compare the value with all other values and not only with the next one
 - third: the last value does not have next one, so it give you an error

Answer (score 0):

By performing the correct query in the first place.

```
SELECT staffID
  FROM staff
  GROUP BY staffID
  HAVING COUNT(staffID) > 1
```

Or if you *need* to know about all staff IDs:

```
SELECT staffID, COUNT(staffID) as qty
  FROM staff
  GROUP BY staffID
```

Answer (score 0):

Just updating your code and i think you have to check the existence first :

```
if (isset($staffID[$i]) && isset($staffID[$i+!])) {
    if($staffID[$i] == $staffID[$i+1])
    {
         $remark = "Not OK. Multiple staff ID selected.";
         $i++;
    }
    else
    {  
         $remark = "OK.";
    }
    $data[$i] = $staffID[$i].','.$remark.'<br />';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You get the error at this line:

```
if($staffID[$i] == $staffID[$i+1])
```

Say for example your `$num_rows` variable is 3. Then the `$staffID` array would have indexes 0, 1 and 2. But what happens at this line I noted is that once `$i` reaches 2 (which is a valid since it's less than 3) you go and do `$i+1` which equals 3. And, as you can see, the index 3 is out of the bounds of the array.

If you wish to do this like you wrote your for loop should be like this:

```
for($i = 0; $i < $num_rows-1; $i++)
```

But, there is a better way without even doing the for loop. You can do it all in the while loop by making use of the [in_array function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php). Or as Ignacio pointed out, you could do it all on the SQL level.

Answer (score 0):

Not a good way to solve this problem. You should use GROUP BY query for this.
 SELECT staffID, COUNT(staffID) as count
 FROM staff
 GROUP BY staffID
 HAVING count > 1

And also about your error. It's because of 
if($staffID[$i] == $staffID[$i+1])

on last iteration $i is equal 4 and $i+1 is 5. But  $staffID array has no element with such key