# PHP CSV file issues(part 2)

Tags: php, csv

- continue on [PHP duplicate staffID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27646693/php-duplicate-staffid?lq=1)
- code
  `$data[0] = 0001,Ali,N,OK`
  `$data[1] = 0002,Abu,N,OK`
  `$data[2] = 0003,Ahmad,N,OK`
  `$data[3] = 0004,Siti,Y,Not OK. Only one manager allowed!`
  `$data[4] = 0005,Raju,Y, Not OK. Only one manager allowed!`

  I write it as following:

  ```
  for($i = 0; $i < 5; $i++)
  {
      $data[i] = $staffID[$i].','.$staffname[$i].','.$ismanager[$i].','.$remark[$i];
  }
  ```
- Next I go to write csv file.

  ```
  $file_format = "staffreport.csv";
  $file = fopen($file_format,"w");
  foreach($data as $line)
  {
      $replace = str_replace(",","|", $line);
      fputcsv($file, array($replace));
      echo $replace.'<br />';
  }
  fclose($file);
  ```
- output (echo $replace)
  0001|Ali|N|OK
  0002|Abu|N|OK
  0003|Ahmad|N|OK
  0004|Raju|Y|Only one manager allowed!
  0005|Siti|Y|Only one manager allowed!
- In CSV file (staffreport.csv)
  0001|Ali|N|OK
  0002|Abu|N|OK
  0003|Ahmad|N|OK
  "0004|Siti|Y|Only one manager allowed!"
  "0005|Raju|Y|Only one manager allowed!"
- Why my csv file have double quote("")? How do I solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change this bit like so.

```
for($i = 0; $i < 5; $i++)
{
    $data[i] = array($staffID[$i],$staffname[$i],$ismanager[$i],$remark[$i]);
}
```

`fputcsv` wants an array of columns it will then insert the separators and quote marks as needed.

fputcsv usually uses commas for separators, if you want pipes: do this:

```
 fputcsv($file, $line,'|');
```

why the quotes? probably because of the spaces.

if you must avoid the quotes,

```
 fputcsv($file, $line,'|','');
```

hope that helps.